# L and ON keeps blinking

Tags: arduino-due

I am not sure why the `ON` LED and the `L` LED keeps blinking on my Arduino.

I was just trying to implement a simple circuit using breadboard, and everything worked fine until I unplugged one wire with the power turned on. I accidentally made the wire touch something in the Arduino, and the LED in the breadboard became extremely bright. Then the `ON` LED and the `L` LED in the Arduino started to keep blinking, and I cannot download code to Arduino anymore. I am using IAR and IAR says `AT91SAM3 reset: Communication breakdown after resetting target. Abort debug session?`.

I think maybe there is a short cut when the wire touched the Arduino... But how can I determine what the problem is? Thank you very much, I am totally new to Arduino and has very limited knowledge about hardware...

Comment: It's dead. Buy another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should split your problem in pieces. Like you cannot get communication with your Arduino again, so check first:

- If you plug in the Arduino / USB, do you get a message on your computer?
- Is it visible in the systems manager?
- Is it visible by the IDE?
- If you connect an adapter (12 or 9V), does it make a difference?
- If you try another Arduino, does it work like it should be?

If you are a beginner, always make sure:

- Never change any wiring with the Arduino on
- Never have dangling wires, if you do not need a wire for the time being, either remove it completely or put it in a breadboard hole that is not used
- Never change components with the Arduino on
- After rewiring/adding/changing components, double check first

Update for comment below because it does not fit as comment:
To buy a cheap/fake (but working) Arduino uno, e.g. 
[Arduino Uno from Aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-UNO-R3-MEGA328P-with-usb-cable-for-Arduino-Compatible-Dropshipping/32241237838.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.17.u1gbjG&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10345_10342_10343_10340_10341_10541_10562_10084_10083_10304_10307_10301_10177_10060_10155_5680017_10154_10056_10055_10539_10537_10312_10536_10059_10313_10314_10534_10533_100031_10103_10073_10102_10557_10142_10107,searchweb201603_25,ppcSwitch_7&btsid=74489aca-62ba-4565-b712-838d7fb5f5d1&algo_expid=4aeaf1be-d6ec-4fc5-8988-7534ccd34d9b-2&algo_pvid=4aeaf1be-d6ec-4fc5-8988-7534ccd34d9b)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice! The Arduino is visible to the IDE, and I will get another Arduino to check tomorrow. It worked fine before, everything changed since the touch.

Comment: I'm afraid something is not working in the Arduino anymore ... and unless you are more expert it might be useful to try to fix it, otherwise buy a new one ... I bought some from China, much cheaper and if something breaks it cost just a few euro.

Comment: What an expensive lesson:-(
Is it proper to ask how buy it from China here, can you tell me? I am at Sweden.

Comment: First I want to say not everybody likes it and it has some disadvantages. First you have to wait from 2 to 10 weeks, also they are fake (so might have some small differences, so far I didn't have many problems). But you can go to e.g. aliexpress and buy the one in my link (does not fit). Also these have a different chip and you probably need to install CH340G drivers (very easy to install).

Comment: Another method to avoid having to buy a new board when you screw something up, is get one with a microcontroller that can be taken out. Half the time, you'll only have damaged the controller and the board survived. Controller is less expensive than a full board. All the first ones had it, not sure about the later ones. Often times you don't need the M3 and an Atmega would've been fine.

Comment: @Mast Good comment ... I noticed most cheap ones don't have a separate chip. However, you can use use the programmed chip without the Uno in a finished project.